# Node on Azure App Service how does it start up?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Angular Universal app that I am deploying to Azure App Service (Windows).

When the app runs locally on my Windows 10 PC it works fine but in the cloud it seems like the `process.cwd()` is different than when I run it locally. This is causing Express.js to look in the wrong place for some view files.

The process pwc should be based on how I executed node, in my case I have a start script in my package.json that executes `"node dist/server.js"`. But I can remove this script and Azure will still start my app. So I think the root of my pwc problem is in how Azure starts up my node app.

Unfortunately Microsoft thinks that some code snippets and a couple John Papa videos is good enough documentation for developers to resolve issues.

Questions

1. Does documentation exist that explains any configuration or
   conventions that the App Service uses to init my node app? Where is
   it?
2. Given the script `"start": "node dist/server.js"` why would `process.cwd()` be different on my local host versus Azure App Service? The file structure is the same in both places.

`const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');`

`app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));`

`Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "D:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\dist\browser"`

- root
- package.json

  - dist

    - server.js
    - browser (client app)
    - server (server app)

Answer (score 3):

1. **Documentation**: Not an exhaustive guide, but this is what I found useful on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fb6977fb-1a5d-49bc-a7f7-b9e836918278/nodejs-having-issue-with-deploying-modern-nodejs-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview):

> Windows Azure Websites uses IISNode to host the Node process inside of IIS. Your Node site is actually given a Named Pipe which receives the incoming requests, not a TCP port like you would use when running locally or hosting yourself.
>
> ...
>
> As a node.js application running on Azure Web Apps, needs a server.js or app.js file as the entrance in the root directory with a web.config file to control the iis

2. **Working Directory**:  When web.config and iisnode are used to run server.js, the rules rewrite the directory to point to where server.js resides.  That is why it isn't able to find a subfolder 'dist'.

I had to change the line above to this, in order for it to work on Azure:

```
const DIST_FOLDER = process.cwd();
```

Another thing I found important was to set the right version of node for your App Service, using **WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION** in App Settings.  Here's a bit more info on that from a blog on MDSN - [NodeJs and NPM versions on Azure App Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/)

Answer (score 1):

Since I am used to hosting Node apps on Linux this totally slipped my mind. The answer is...

see web.config

Comment: You can always run on top of Linux workers on App Service, either on built-in containers or custom - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds themselves here put this in your server.ts file to work both locally and on azure

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
const distFolderExists = fs.existsSync(join(process.cwd(), 'dist'));
const DIST_FOLDER = distFolderExists ? join(process.cwd(), 'dist') : process.cwd();
```

big thanks to KayS for their answer - really helpful.